# VSTS Release Phase Condition

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipeline including 3 phases. The first phase has some load testing I use to warm-up a website. When I run out of VUM, the load testing of course fails.

I configured an agentless phase (second) to warm-up the site by hand (run only when a previous phase failed).

Then after the warmup (either by hand or by load test) I want to swap some azure slot and call some api's in the last (third) phase. I can't find a condition for this phase. It needs to run only when the manual phase is approved (and not when rejected) or when the load test did work (aka got enough VUM)

BTW; I tried creating a manual condition using a variable. But i couldn't find a way (except maybe by hand) to set the variable to true when approving the serverless phase.

(sorry i could think of a better short title)

Comment: How do you configure manual approve for agentless phase?

Comment: Maybe i'm not completely clear. But i mean the following: [Utility: Manual intervention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/manual-intervention)

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do it through Release Phase Condition, you can put the necessary logical in the same phase.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to ad a manual action to an agent phase. And also how do i configure the remaining actions after the manual load test? I didn't find the rigth config for a single phase either. Conditions on actions are almost the same.

Comment: How do you warm-up the site by hand and what do you mean manual phase (config, approve)?

Comment: By manual phase a mean a non agent phase with a manual action. When done, it is currently followed by an other agent phase swapping slots and calling some api's. The manual warmup is just visiting the  pages in the warmup slot.

Comment: How about using multiple environments in a release?